# Hazelcast alternative for redis database

Tags: redis, hazelcast

Is there any alternative for redis database feature in HazelCast ? I could see there is instances within hazelcast. But are they similiar to redis databases ?
For different instances will there be single tcp connection ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure I get the question. Can you please elaborate on your idea? In general Hazelcast is not a database but I really don't think I can answer your request.

Comment: @noctarius : Redis databse is nothing but isolated keyspace. I wanted a way to isolate certain keys under one keyspace.

Comment: So like different maps? Yeah perfectly possible.

Comment: @noctarius Not different maps but different keyspace itself. I can workaround this with multimap. But I am thinking weather it support by itself.

Comment: Can you please update the question with some pseudo code on what you want to achieve? Still not really sure what you think of. I guess you want a list of values assigned to a single key. That is either a MultiMap or put an ArrayList into the map. Latter is not recommended for large amounts of values.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by keyspace? Are you asking if Hazelcast has a data structure that allows you to store multiple values against the same key?

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast and Redis shares some similarities but they're fundamentally different.

Hazelcast is an IMDG and Redis is an in memory database.

If you like the features from IMDG but still wanted to use your existing Redis infrastructure, you can checkout the [Redisson](https://redisson.org) project. It provides similar features like Hazelcast for Redis.

**Please note**: I am a member of the Redisson team and please consider my answer is biased towards the project.